# Strip a comma and whitespace thats after it from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with a Postcode Finder and some of the address elements i.e County are returning empty at times as a **", "**

I'm looking to strip them from the string to return a more readable address format

Example Data is JSON :

```
{
"latitude": 53.381130218505859,
"longitude": -1.4663739204406738,
"addresses": [
    "Crucible Enterprises Ltd, 55 Norfolk Street, , , , Sheffield, South Yorkshire",
    "Crucible Theatre, 55 Norfolk Street, , , , Sheffield, South Yorkshire",
    "Sheffield Crucible Productions Ltd, 55 Norfolk Street, , , , Sheffield, South Yorkshire",
    "Sheffield Theatres Crucible Trust, 55 Norfolk Street, , , , Sheffield, South Yorkshire",
    "The City Of Sheffield Theatre Trust, 55 Norfolk Street, , , , Sheffield, South Yorkshire"
]
}
```

As you can see there's a lot of commas and spaces directly after with no data in.

How do I go about doing this? My current code is :

```
$.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/address',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { _token: token, postcode: postcode},
                success: function( data )
                {
                    $('.addresses').html('');

                    $.each(data, function(k, v)
                    {
                        address = v.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');

                        $('.addresses').append('<option value="">'+ address +'</option>');
                    })
                }
            }
        )
```

Comment: Arent those commas part of the logic, like columns? Wont it ruin the logic to remove those before sending it to the server?

Comment: That's the data I'm getting it back. The idea here being it's just a neater string from the end user to read.

Comment: Yes, I understand. The finder I used, separated entries (=field/properties/columns) by comma. For example `field1, field2, field3, field4`. If you remove the commas you will not know whether field4 or field3 was empty. If that does not matter in your process it is all fine :-) I would advise nonetheless to read the specs of the API and get the correct field if provided accordingly.

Comment: It sounds like it's more of an issue with properly parsing the return for the correct  address parts. The commas do have a meaning, which will be lost if dupes are removed.

Comment: You should watch it like a csv and not remove the commas since they are most likely part of the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to clean them up.

```js
var str = "Crucible Enterprises Ltd, 55 Norfolk Street, , , , Sheffield, South Yorkshire"
var cleaned = str.replace(/,(\s,)+/, ',')
console.log(cleaned)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this without the use of regular expressions.

```
const address = "The City Of Sheffield Theatre Trust, 55 Norfolk Street, , , , Sheffield, South Yorkshire"

const cleanAddress = address.split(", ")
    .filter(section => !!section)
    .join(", ");

// The City Of Sheffield Theatre Trust, 55 Norfolk Street, Sheffield, South Yorkshire
```

This uses the fact that an empty string `""` is a [falsy value.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Adding this to your code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/address",
  dataType: "json",
  data: { _token: token, postcode: postcode },
  success: function(data) {
    $(".addresses").html("");

    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
     address = v.split(", ")
         .filter(section => !!section)
         .join(", ");

      $(".addresses").append('<option value="">' + address + "</option>");
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the extra `,` by using `regex`.

Try this.

```js
let str = "Crucible Enterprises Ltd, 55 Norfolk Street, , , , Sheffield, South Yorkshire";
let regex = /(,\s){2,}/g
console.log(str.replace(regex, ", "));
```

In your code you could use like below.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/address",
  dataType: "json",
  data: { _token: token, postcode: postcode },
  success: function(data) {
    $(".addresses").html("");

    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
      address = v.replace(/\s+|(,\s){2,}/g, " ");

      $(".addresses").append('<option value="">' + address + "</option>");
    });
  }
});
```